# context.getExternalFilesDir(null) is null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to debug a problem I am having in my app.  The issue is that getExternalFiles(dir) returns null in my android app but I am not sure why.  I have the necessary permissions.  This is a bug which exists on multiple devices and versions of android (2.3.5 and up).  Let me know if you need any more information.

The line of code which is the problem is:

path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/database/mydata.db";

or

path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/database/mydata.db";

Thank you.

Comment: @Tarsem, I have a check for that but since this is proprietary code, I'm hesitant about posting too much.

Comment: @KenWolf, No.  The exact error is IllegalStateException:  File null/database/mydata.db

Comment: According to the docs this will return null if external storage is not mounted. Are you sure it is mounted? "Returns null if external storage is not currently mounted so it could not ensure the path exists; you will need to call this method again when it is available."

Comment: @KenWolf, the other possibility we have is context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/database/mydata.db" if the  media is not mounted.  those are the two possible locations and one of those methods is returning null as a parent directory

Comment: Your database is either in the internal or external storage - where have you put it? `getFilesDir()` is internal storage. `getExternalFilesDir()` is external storage. I assume you haven't put it in two different places? It's not going to appear in both magically...

Comment: no.  the location of the database depends of if external storage is available or not.  that determines where the database is stored

Comment: OK.. so, to answer your question: `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` returning `null` is a valid response and is returning null because the external storage is not currently available.

Comment: I've added it as an answer for completeness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` returning `null` is a perfectly valid response.

From the docs:

> **Returns**
>
> The path of the directory holding application files on external storage. Returns `null` if external storage is not currently mounted so it could not ensure the path exists; you will need to call this method again when it is available.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

So it looks like the devices where it is failing have an external SD card that is currently not available (user has mounted it, removed it, etc.).

You will have to check for this case using something like `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` and handle accordingly if it's not there.

Answer (score 3):

```
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true; 
        } 
        return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be permissions issue
Try to add this as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is ignored by API level 11

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the `context`

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/database/mydata.db";
```

I passed a global context, that obtain from a separate class `_MyApplication`. But I forgot to add it in the manifest. so, the solution was In the manifest :

```
<application
        android:name="._MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true" 
.......
```