# how to save a file in android, ENOENT IOexception

Tags: android

How to save a file in android?
I have the following code:

```
 final File file = new File(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
```

and I get

```
03-21 11:31:29.903: W/System.err(31668): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-21 11:31:29.903: W/System.err(31668):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
```

exception
My complete code for the saving of the file is the following:

```
final File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                // file.mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try {
                try {
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    output.flush();
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
                Log.i("save_file", "save to disk is ok");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I also have the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can some one please point out what I'm I doing wrong, thanks

**EDITED**:
The problem was the name of the file that i wanted to save, so it shouldn't be contain restricted chars, mine was in this format:`"xxx/xxx.jpg"` so '/' is not a valid char for a file name. Thanks

Comment: Check  this `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) before  context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`

Comment: so if i have the phone connected to a usb on a pc it might not work?

Comment: it's becoz your SDcard not mounted to your phone when your phone connected with USB

Comment: go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547771/context-getexternalfilesdirnull-is-null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547771/context-getexternalfilesdirnull-is-null) and read this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of context.getExternalFilesDir(null) even though it seems same.

here is my code:

```
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mFolder = new File(extr + "/MainFolder_Photo");

        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
        mSubFolder = new File(strF + "/Pictures");

        if (!mSubFolder.exists()) {
            mSubFolder.mkdir();
        } 

        // check file are there or not;// if present delete

        try {


        File yourDir = new File(mSubFolder.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {

            if (f.length()>0){

        f.delete();

            }

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        // file name
        String s = "Puzzle_Photo.png";

        File f = new File(mSubFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

        strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        OutputStream output;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(f);
            URL url = new URL("file://" + filePath);// your data
            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            output.close();
            input.close();

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to store file on SD card,

```
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/yourdir/");
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }

   File file = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/filename
                 .txt");
      final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            try {
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                output.flush();
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
            Log.i("save_file", "save to disk is ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i am not sure about your input file.

Comment: a actually need to store it on the phone and not on a SD card, I think that context.getExternalFilesDir(null) gives me the phone

Comment: sorry for mess, i will put shortly how to store on phone memory

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to store file on phone memory,

```
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File dir = cw.getDir("EMD Systems", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File Filedir = new File(dir + "/Zip");
        if (!Filedir.exists()) {
            Filedir.mkdirs();
        }
    File file = new File(Filedir.getAbsolutePath() + "/filename
             .txt");
  final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            output.flush();
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
        Log.i("save_file", "save to disk is ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```